# Entity Framework tracking issue with multiple objects of the same ID

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

I'm learning.

I'm using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in a .netcoreapp 2.1, the point is to expose static data through an API.

Currently, I have the data in a json object. Lets keep the examples simple, I'm trying to expose a list of sandwhiches and ingredients for those sandwhiches. Sandwhiches come in various type (bagels, long, short, etc.)

First of all, I'm not entirely sure that using EF is the correct tool, but as I'll have to manage those items later on (being able to order food) I started there. If there is a better tool for it I'm all ears, but for now my question is to expose that using EF.

I'm reading the json that is hardcoded in the app and using it as a starting point for my `DbContext`. I just deserialize it in my constructor and load it up in my context object, which would then be exposed through the API. Works like a charm with the todo-list template project.

Here's what it looks like, I just added more DBSets for my needs

```
public class EatupContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<FoodType> Types { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FoodItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

`FoodType` is an `int` with an ID and a name. Same for `Ingredients`.
Items are the sandwhiches and look like this

```
public class FoodItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FoodType Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

In the json that I'm reading (which is mapped like the c# objects), all id's start at 0 for all objects. So `Types` go from 0 to 7, ingredients from 0 to 105, and food items from 0 to 60.

This is causing an id tracking issue for the entity framework, because there are multiple objets with the same ID. Even though they're in different `DBSets`, which is what confuses me. From my (flawed?) understanding, two tables (DBSets?) can have duplicate id's. I can have a  sandwich id 0, of type 0, with ingredients 0, 1, 2 and 3. It would seem even *more* confusing to me to have types going from 0 to 7, then ingredients from 8 to 113, and sandwiches from 114 to 174. That'd be just really odd to me in a database point of view.

Here is the exact error I am getting :

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Ingredient' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. 

When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. 

Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap<TKey>.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
```

With the following stacktrace :

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap<TKey>.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap<TKey>.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, bool updateDuplicate)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, bool acceptChanges)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, bool acceptChanges, Nullable<EntityState> forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode node, bool force)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph<TState>(EntityEntryGraphNode node, TState state, Func<EntityEntryGraphNode, TState, bool> handleNode)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph<TState>(EntityEntryGraphNode node, TState state, Func<EntityEntryGraphNode, TState, bool> handleNode)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState entityState, bool forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityStates(IEnumerable<object> entities, EntityState entityState)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.UpdateRange(IEnumerable<object> entities)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<TEntity>.UpdateRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
EatUp.Backend.Controllers.EatupController..ctor(EatupContext context) in EatupController.cs
+
            _context.Items.UpdateRange(completeModel.Items);
lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

And this happens in the controller, in the following code :

```
    private readonly EatupContext _context;

    public EatupController(EatupContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        var completeModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EatUpDataModel>(EatUpDataSet.Complete);

        _context.Items.UpdateRange(completeModel.Items);  //fails here
        _context.Types.UpdateRange(completeModel.Types);
        _context.Ingredients.UpdateRange(completeModel.Ingredients);

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

It also fails if I use `AddRange` ; I'm using `Update` so I dont have to check if the set is empty or not, I just erase it with the latest data from the json.

I'm not sure what approach I should take from this, I really don't want to edit that json manually, but I don't see how I can tell EF that those are separate objects other than what I'm already doing.

EDIT:

I have edited all my id's manually to have only unique ones, and I still get the error.

The only time an ID appears twice, is when the same ingredient is used in different sandwiches, which should be acceptable.

Now i'm 200% confused, what am I missing ?

Comment: Can you show the code which fails and exception stacktrace?

Comment: Sure, It's edited in the original post.

Comment: If you're supposed to use EF and store everything in a DB...why do you still need to read all those things from your JSON file? It's a useless duplication. Pick one or the other. Also: not sure but you may want to add types first, then ingredients and finally items. Did you also clean your DB?

Comment: I'm using that JSON to generate the initial content of the DB. Then it would not be used again.

Comment: I know I am late, but I faced the same issue and found why (Well I think, still debugging). Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you shouldn't need to tell EF that those are separate objects. It should work it out. Can you copy and paste your migration?